# How to list all versions of a pecl package

Tags: php, pear, pecl

Is it possible to list all versions of a pecl package?

`pecl search xdebug`, for example, only lists the latest 3.0.1 version. But I'm wanting the latest 2.x version.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pecl list` to list all installed packages, which will return something like:

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package    Version State
pdo_sqlsrv 5.9.0   stable
redis      5.3.3   stable
sqlsrv     5.9.0   stable
```

Or, you can use `pecl info {package}` to list information about a specific package.

So far as I know, you cannot list all available versions directly from command line. Your best bet, is just heading over to [pecl.php.net](https://pecl.php.net/) and [searching](https://pecl.php.net/package-search.php) for your package, which will list all package versions, along with their release dates.

Answer (score 3):

The pear command line installer (which is behind `pecl`) has no native way of listing all package versions.

You can only query the [REST API](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/core.rest.php#core.rest.fileformats.r-package-allreleases2xml) yourself: https://pear.php.net/rest/r/mime_type/allreleases2.xml

The package name must be lowercase in that URL.

Comment: He's not wrong.  https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/mcrypt/allreleases.xml and https://pecl.php.net/rest/r/xdebug/allreleases.xml worked for me