# How to get specific version of a package with pecl install?

Tags: xdebug, pecl

Xdebug was updated to version 3 and currently it will be installed in its latest version when I run

```
pecl install xdebug
```

This broke a Dockerfile and an XDebug setup. While I plan to upgrade to xdebug@3 in the long run, I want for now to force installing xdebug 2.9. How can I achieve that?

I tried doing

```
pecl install xdebug@2
```

and similar approaches.

How do I list all versions of a package and how do I force installing a specific version with pecl?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65399058/457268

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You you have to provide [exact version via flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399058/how-to-list-all-versions-of-a-pecl-package),

```
pecl install xdebug-2.9.8
```